# Automator (2.5) Script to create folder based on file name and move file to folder

Tags: applescript, automator

Thank you for taking the time to look.  I am trying to create a workflow using automator 2.5 that will read the video files in my directory, create a folder with the file name, and move the file into the newly created folder.  I have tried multiple scripts available online and encountered errors.  Then I created this hybrid script which does not error or do anything.  any assistance would be appreciated (I am not new to programming but inexperience with this version of automator)
[image: Screenshot of script]

Comment: IMO This is so much easier doing it directly in **Terminal**. Just _change directory_ `cd ...` to the folder containing the `.mov` files and use the following _command_: `for f in *.mov; do mkdir -p "${f%.*}" && mv -vn "$f" ./"${f%.*}"; done`  **NOTE:** As usual, always ensure you have proper backups before preforming any actions that will change the contents of the filesystem.

Comment: Your example is great when my file extensions are all the same.  Sometimes I have multiple files with the same name but different extensions.  I appreciate the response though, it is making me consider another approach.

Comment: Then use, e.g., `for f in *.*; do ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your files selected in the front Finder window, running this following code in Script Editor.app should accomplish what you're looking to achieve

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set selectedFiles to selection as alias list
    set containingFolder to container of (item 1 of selectedFiles) --as alias
    repeat with i from 1 to count of selectedFiles
        set foldersRef to (a reference to folders of containingFolder)
        set foldersRefItems to name of (contents of foldersRef)
        set thisItem to item i of selectedFiles
        set fileName to (text items 1 thru -5) of (name of thisItem as text) as string
        if fileName is not in foldersRefItems then
            move thisItem to (make new folder at containingFolder ¬
                with properties {name:fileName})
        else
            move thisItem to folder fileName of containingFolder
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: You are a GOD sent.  That worked perfectly! I wish I could up vote this a few Hundred million times for all the hours you just saved me, thank you!

Comment: Is there any way to make the script not error out if there are two files with the same name and allow both to be moved to the folder?  EXAMPLE: File1.abc & File1.xyz

Comment: I just updated the code in my post so the script will not error out if there are files containing the same names. Let me know if you run into any other issues

Comment: Thanks again.  For anyone trying to do this in Automator, simply replace my Applescript code in the original post with the answer here.  This also works as a service, allowing you to launch this directly from finder.